# use ggplot2 with kde plots of ks package

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

I'm using [`ks` package](https://rdocumentation.org/packages/ks/versions/1.10.7/topics/plot.kde) to calculate and plot bivariate kernel density estimations. It works great, but I want to use ggplot to plot the estimations instead.

I could try and create a custom function to prepare a data frame and stuff for ggplot but I have a feeling more experienced users of R could do this with less effort.

So, how do I do it?

Here is an example scenario of ks::kde:

```
data <- cbind(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
kd <- ks::kde(data)
plot(kd, display = "slice", col = viridis::viridis(20))
plot(kd, display = "image", col = viridis::viridis(20))
plot(kd, display = "persp", col.fun = viridis::viridis)
```

The above code should give you the following plots. How do I use ggplot to achive these plots?

**EDIT**: I *need* to use the estimations calculated by `ks` package. The native functions provided by `ggplot2` uses a package named `MASS`. So that won't do.

[image: slice plot]
[image: image plot]
[image: perspective plot]

Comment: ggplot2 will create the first two, but the 3D one is going to be a tough one.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, no problem. I don't actually need the third one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first two are straightforward in ggplot. Here's a fully reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- cbind(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))

d <- ggplot(as.data.frame(data), aes(V1, V2)) + 
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  theme_bw()

d + geom_density2d(aes(colour = after_stat(level)), bins = 5)
```

[image]

```r
d + geom_density2d_filled()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To specifically use the output of `ks::kde()`, we need to convert its data from a matrix into long format using `reshape2::melt`, but then it is still very easy to plot in ggplot:

```r
set.seed(1)

data <- cbind(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
kd   <- ks::kde(data)

library(ggplot2)
```

**Contour Plot**

```
ggplot(reshape2::melt(kd$estimate)) +
  geom_contour(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, z = value, color = stat(level)),
               bins = 5) +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**Filled contour plot**

```r
ggplot(reshape2::melt(kd$estimate)) +
  geom_contour_filled(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, z = value, fill = stat(level)),
               bins = 9) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

**Raster image**

```r
ggplot(reshape2::melt(kd$estimate)) +
  geom_raster(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I have to use the kde estimations from `ks` package. AFAIK, ggplot2 uses some package named MASS.

Comment: @klaus you are right about the 2d estimates coming from the MASS package. See my update to learn how to use the output from `ks::kde` instead.

Comment: The contour plot doesn't give the same output with the dataset I'm working with. (Bivariate normal was just an example.) But the raster plot is working and I get the idea of how it's supposed to work. Thanks.